# error al obtener valor de JTextField

Tags: java

tengo unos JTextField declarados tal que asi:

```
tname = new JTextField("",15);
tinteresante = new JTextField("",15);
tguion = new JTextField("",15);
tpersonajes = new JTextField("",15);
```

Y a la hora de coger el texto para pasarlo a string me devuelve null a pesar de haber escrito en ellos, asi es como obtengo los strings:

```
        String name = tname.getSelectedText();
        String interesante1 = tinteresante.getSelectedText();
        String guion1 = tguion.getSelectedText();
        String personajes1 = tpersonajes.getSelectedText();
        String bandasonora1 = tbandasonora.getSelectedText();
        String extra1 = textra.getSelectedText();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema esta en el metodo que utlizas para obtener los Strings del JTextField, utilizas el getSelectedText() y para que este no te devuelva null debes de tener seleccionado un texto en especfico. Para obtener todo el texto que tenga utiliza el metodo getText().

Comment: Hola, más parece un comentario que una respuesta, trata de acompañar con ejemplos tu respuesta.